# General solution of a specific eigenvalue problem.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics, sturm-liouville, linear-pde

Consider a Schroedinger-like equation with a generalized harmonic potential:

$$
\left(\sum_i\mu_i^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}-\sum_{ij}\Omega_{ij}x_ix_j+E\right)\Psi=0,
$$
where indices run from 1 to $N$, $x_i$ are real coordinates, $\mu_i$ are positive real numbers, and $\Omega$ is a positive-definite symmetric real matrix.

Is the following statement valid:

Any eigenvalue of the problem is determined by a $N$-tuple of non-negative integer numbers $(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_N)$ as
$$
E_{n_1n_2\dots n_N}=\sum_{i=1}^N\left(1+2n_i\right)\omega_i,
$$
where $\omega$'s are the square roots of the eigenvalues of the matrix $\tilde\Omega$:
$$\tilde\Omega_{ij}=\mu_i\mu_j\Omega_{ij}$$?

If the general solution of the problem is known I would be thankful for corresponding hints and/or references.

Comment: I made a small edit to your post and added a few tags.  Hope this is OK.

Comment: I think I was able to prove the statement, except for showing that $\tilde\Omega$ is positive-definite. I would be thankful for any hint concerning a proof of the latter property.

Comment: The proof of the positive definiteness has appeared to be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a bunch of *N* linear oscillators, a system readily diagonalizable, upon defining real coordinates $y_i\equiv x_i/\mu_i$, so you have 
$$
\left(\sum_i \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y_i^2}-\sum_{ij}\tilde \Omega_{ij}y_iy_j+E\right)\Psi=0,
$$
with $\tilde \Omega$ real, symmetric (symmetrize by the *y*s) and positive.

As such, it is orthogonally diagonalizable to its real positive eigenvalues' matrix $\tilde { \tilde \Omega}_{ij}=\delta_{ij}\omega^2_i$, with eigenvectors $z_i$, to wit
$$
\left(\sum_i ( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z_i^2}-  \omega_{i}^2 z_i^2)+E\right)\Psi=0,
$$
*N* decoupled harmonic oscillators.